# Display message afer save is successful BlockUI Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel, asp.net-2.0, blockui

I want to display a status message after a server side postback. Currently to do this,

1. I use blockUI for blocking a
   div while the save is in progress
2. I unblock the div with a custom End request handler for my update panel
3. To display status messages, I use scriptmanager's registerstartupscript() in my try catch block on server side code. All works well, however this displays the status messages before the div is unblocked.

How do I show my success/error messages only after the div has been unblocked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pageLoading` or `pageLoaded` [script manager event handers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx) instead of `endRequest`, i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(PageLoadingHandler);
    function PageLoadingHandler(sender, args) 
    {      
         // hide your blockUI div here
    }
</script>
```

### -----------------

Or you have another option. Write message on server callback to hidden field and then in your `endRequest` handler hide div, check if there is message in hidden field and if message exists display it.

Comment: the problem is that since I am using scriptmanager's startup script to display messages, they always get executed first no matter what handler I attach the unblock.

Comment: pageLoading should work: Raised after the response from the server to an asynchronous postback is received but before any content on the page is updated.

Comment: I have added another option... but it seems to be dirty hack :)

Comment: Thanks Pavel, that hack worked like a charm =) Offtopic, doing this task the proper way would you recommend doing the whole job with JSON & web methods ? What do you recommend ? I am starting to think that I am doing the whole thing in a wrong way .... maybe

Comment: In my projects I'm trying to use "JSON(jQuery,ajax) & web methods" and avoid any updatepanels. In this case you can handle by yourself what data to send, what to do with this data, how to parse received and sent data and how your UI will work during server callback.